# Error message says that I can't assign to function in python

Tags: python

How do I make it so that 'z' would be added to a random variable in the list?

```
import random

a1 = ''
a2 = ''
a3 = ''
a4 = ''
a5 = ''
a6 = ''
a7 = ''
a8 = ''
a9 = ''

la = [a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8,a9]

random.choice(la) += 'z'
```

Comment: Why do you have that many variables? why don't use the array instead?

Comment: Well, as it turns out .. you *can't* assign a value to a function [call].

Answer (score 0):

Since Python strings are immutable, in order to change the string *in the array*, you need to reassign an element of the array, not another variable. To do this, we need to pick an index, not a value of the array element itself:

```
la[random.randrange(len(la))] += 'z'
```

Comment: I think you're not addressing the real problem with the original code. The problem is that augmented assignment with a function call on the LHS is plain invalid no matter on whether the return value is mutable or not. Without this the solution doesn't seem to make much sense since you still don't explain why you suddenly could do this by your example (the strings are still mutable).